# Salesforce Marketing Cloud Architecture

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, architecture

I have tried searching for an SFMC architecture diagram to understand how to links and interacts withe the normal SFDC platform.

All I could find is this: [**Security, Privacy and Architecture of the Salesforce Marketing Cloud**](https://help.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0150M000003L3IsQAK)

Any link to a more helpful document or help page will be welcome.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on precisely what you are looking for information about?

Answer (score 7):

Most of the details are outlined in the [**Marketing Cloud Connect**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/) documentation.  When most people get into the guts of the connector, they realize that it's not as simple or as straightforward as described.

Here's a visual that I've been working on:

[image: Marketing Cloud Connect Data Flow Diagram]

Comment: is there any official documentation that contains diagrams about Email Studio? Thanks in advanced. I saw a couple of them but are really primitive.

Comment: Love the diagram / visual Adam