# Will Synchronized Data Extension also sync data from SFMC to Sales Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, marketing-cloud-connect

Does Synchronize Data Extension also sync data from SFMC to Sales Cloud or is it just one-way? If yes, can we update Synchronized DE using query?

Comment: You can't use Queries to update Synchronized Data Extensions.  You can't select them as the target Data Extension.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs - Is there a way to update Synchronized Data Extensions?

Comment: Yes, in Sales Cloud.  Or by mapped profile attributes in the stock preference center.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs - Can we make a change to the data in SFMC? Or is it Read-Only.

Comment: Added an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only certain data points from SFMC get sent back to Sales Cloud.  It's not a two-way sync of data.

Subscriber status, unsubscribes for SF sends and mapped profile attribute values are the only data points will update SF objects (aside from tracking data).

[**Here's an overview**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/199759/5202) of the architecture.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Marketing Cloud connector, then data is synchronized in both directions. The connector sync's data every 15 mins or so.

Tracking data - opens, bounces, clicks etc. is also fed into Sales Cloud.

It would be unnecessary to synchronize using Queries, - unless you have custom feeds etc that you want to also want to sync back.

Comment: How do you know it's synchronized in both directions?